# Django SlugFields change during South schemamigration

Tags: python, django, django-south

I just did a South schemamigration and it outputted that all the Slug fields changed, but I didn't change any of the code for the slug fields.

The original South migration files have the slug fields as:

```
'slug': ('django.db.models.fields.SlugField', [], {'db_index': 'True', 'unique': 'True', 'max_length': '50', 'blank': 'True'})
```

But now, South has the slug fields as:

```
'slug': ('django_extensions.db.fields.AutoSlugField', [], {'populate_from': "'name'", 'allow_duplicates': 'False', 'max_length': '50', 'separator': "u'-'", 'blank': 'True', 'unique': 'True', 'overwrite': 'False', 'db_index': 'True'})
```

Does anyone know why this change happened?

Comment: Have you updated South or Django? Are either in a `requirements.txt` without a specified version? Could they have been updated by pip? Could you post the model definition, or at least the field? Have you changed db backends?

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem was that South was updated from one machine to another.